# Recursive wildcard search and replace

Tags: bash, replace, sed

I'm trying to figure out how to get `sed` to replace a wildcard string recursively.

I need to change

```
style="position:absolute;top:522;left:118">
```

to

```
style="position:absolute;top:522px;left:118px">
```

The numbers need to be a wildcard since they constantly change. Also if there is a `px` there it needs to do nothing.

Comment: I think you mean "globally", not "recursively".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have

```
sed -r 's|(style="position:absolute;top:[0-9]+)(px)?(;left:[0-9]+)(px)?(">)|\1px\3px\5|g' file
```

Or perhaps a little less specific:

```
sed -r -e 's@((top|left):[0-9]+)(px)?@\1px@g' file
```

Add `-i` to edit the file in-place.

Comment: be careful, you will get screwed if there are different measures like left:2em.

Comment: Ran the script across a lot of pages with no problems.  I just wanted to add <!DOCTYPE html> to a site to make it responsive.  This fixed the positioning problem.  Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `sed`,

```
sed 's/\(:[0-9]\+\)\(px\)\?/\1px/g' yourfile
```

If your `sed` supports `-E` option,

```
sed -E 's/(:[0-9]+)(px)?/\1px/g' yourfile
```

**Test:**

```
$ cat file
style="position:absolute;top:522;left:118;right:28px"> 

$ sed 's/\(:[0-9]\+\)\(px\)\?/\1px/g' file
style="position:absolute;top:522px;left:118px;right:28px">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk '/style/ && !/px">/ {sub(/">/,"px&")}1' file
```

If line does contain  `style`, but is missing the `px`, add it.